# Display profile picture of a user which is stored in a folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, ravendb

I have uploaded the profile picture of a user to a folder and saved its path in db.Here is my code for uploading

```
       public ActionResult UploadPic(FileManagement fmanage, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            string email = User.Identity.Name;

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var FileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", Guid.NewGuid(),   Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads"), FileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);

            using (var session = DocumentStore.OpenSession("RavenMemberShip"))
            {

                var query = from q in Session.Query<Registration>() where q.Email == email select q;
                if (query.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var updated in query)
                    {
                        updated.FileName = FileName;
                        updated.Path = path;
                        session.SaveChanges();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else ModelState.AddModelError("", "Remove the errors and try again");
        return View();
    }
```

Now,i want to show the uploaded profile picture in a image control.
In my view i have a img control.
            @using (Html.BeginForm())

```
         {
        <img src="@Url.Action("UploadPic", "FileManagementController")" />
         }
```

Code for displaying picture of a user who is using his account.I have get the path of the picture and returned a file based on that path.
How can i display  that picture in the image control that is in the view.

```
         public ActionResult DisplayPic(FileManagement fm)
          {
             string ipath;
             string UserName = User.Identity.Name;
              var getPath = from p in Session.Query<Registration>()
                      where p.Email == UserName
                      select p;
        if (getPath.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var imgpath in getPath)
            {
                ipath = imgpath.Path;
                return base.File(ipath, "image/jpg");
            }
        }


        return View();
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
User @Url.Content() and pass image path in parameter.

{
<img src="@Url.Content(Model.Path)" />
}
```

Comment: @Url.Content(ipath);
 <img src="@Url.Content(Model.Path)" />
it is giving a compile time error The name 'ipath' does not exist in the current context.I dit not get that how to pass ipath in parameter that i get in DisplayPic Controller.
Please clear it to me.

Comment: pass image path instead of Model.Path, if u have path of that image.

Comment: i have path in ipath variable that is in DisplayPic Controller.when i give it to src attribute of img like this.<img src="@ipath" /> A compile time error occurs ipath does not exist in current context.I dont know how to pass a variable from controller to view.Can you write the sample code??

Comment: we can not get controller variable in view. can you please send your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067187/unable-to-read-view-bag-value-from-controller-to-view.Check this link for my code.The path should be stored in viewbag and this view Bag value should be given to Image src attribute.

Answer (score 2):

youu can use below code also if you are enable to get image Path from Model.

```
public ActionResult DisplayPic()
{
   var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads"), "heroAccent.png");
   return File(path, "image/jpeg");
}

<img src="@Url.Action("DisplayPic","FileManagement")" />
```

Pass just pass 'FileManagement' as controller name instead of 'FileManagementController'.